# how to access second span tag under class in xpath

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, inspect-element

I am trying to access data from XPath for the below data. I wanted to get the Hostname - 192.81.xx.xx and ISP - Random

```
<div class="left">
 <p class="information">
    <span>Hostname</span>
    <span>192.81.xx.xx</span>
 </p>
 <p class="information">
    <span>ISP</span>
    <span>Random</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Xpath I've Tried - //div[@class="left"]//p[@class="information"]//span[contains(text(), "Hostname:")]

Answer (score 1):

this xpath

```
//div[@class="left"]//p[@class="information"]//span
```

will return 4 nodes.

```
<span>Hostname</span>
<span>192.81.xx.xx</span>
<span>ISP</span>
<span>Random</span>
```

based on the HTML that you've shared.

you should use `find_elements` that will return list of web elements.

Also, if you use the above XPath with `find_element` it will always fetch the first matching node which is `<span>Hostname</span>`

to get specific node:

1. to get `192.81.xx.xx` use the below XPath:

   ```
   //div[@class="left"]//p[@class="information"]//span[1]
   ```
2. for random:

   ```
   //div[@class="left"]//p[2][@class="information"]//span[2]
   ```

Comment: I wanted to get only values i.e., 192.81.xx.xx and Random only

Comment: you can get it from list which is more relevant in your case, if you wish to have separate `find_element` command use the above two XPath that I have updated just now.

Comment: How can we fetch the second node data only

Comment: This is not the expectations here at stackoverflow, user should not be changing original question, if you have follow up questions, create a new thread.

Comment: @cruisepandey  I see you won't get points from the author here, so I gave it :)

Comment: @Prophet: That's the most frustrating thing here at StackOverflow. Anyway thnx, cheers !

Comment: I know, colleague :)